Cannot get filename from CRM_Core_Error::createDebugLogger() under 5.76.alpha1
 $file_log = CRM_Core_Error::createDebugLogger();
 $logFileName = $file_log->_filename;

under 5.74.4 gives the current log file.
Under my instance 5.76.alpha1 it $logFileName is null.
This is because $file_log->_filename does not exist, it is $file_log->filename, which is private and cannot be retrieved.
Log viewer, which uses this, appears to be working in the Demo environment.
I'm not sure this is the right place to be raising this, but I'm not sure where else to do it.

Just yesterday master updated pear/log to 1.14. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30520. Use CRM_Core_Error::generateLogFileName() in 5.76+
I also just put up a PR for the logviewer extension and earlier today for cv. I expect when the demo rebuilds logviewer will stop working there.

Indeed, I discovered that pear/log was at 1.14 and it seemed to be the reason why logviewer stopped working. I cheated and copied pear/log 1.13.x to my test location, and now logviewer works.

There's a new release of logviewer with an update for this now.
